# Ecto: How to preload a belongs_to association of a has_many association?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a `Meetup` model that `has_many :rsvps`, and `Rsvp` model with `belongs_to :user`.

Here's my endpoint:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  one_hour_ago = Timex.now
                 |> Timex.shift(hours: -1)
                 |> Timex.to_unix
  meetups = from(m in Meetup, where: m.timestamp >= ^one_hour_ago)
            |> Repo.all
            |> Repo.preload(:rsvps)
  render conn, meetups: meetups
end
```

and my view

```
def render("index.json", %{ meetups: meetups }) do
  render_many(meetups, ParrotApi.MeetupView, "meetup.json")
end

def render("meetup.json", %{ meetup: meetup }) do
  %{
    id: meetup.id,
    rsvped_users: Enum.map(meetup.rsvps, fn rsvp ->
      rsvp |> Repo.preload(:user)
      user = rsvp.user
      %{
        image_url: user.image_url,
        interests: user.interests,
      }
    end),
  }
end
```

However, it is failing with `** (Plug.Conn.WrapperError) ** (KeyError) key :image_url not found in: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>`

It feels wrong to be importing `Repo` to a view. Is there a way to do this in the controller?

Comment: How about doing `|> Repo.preload(rsvps: [:user])` in the controller instead?

Comment: that worked!!! wow! thanks!!

Comment: I would suggest not to preload in views - it's a path to a lot of pain and performance issues. Views should be pure functions - without side effects - this makes them extremely easily testable, cacheable, etc. Your implementation also suffers from N+1 queries - for each rsvp you will query separately for the user. Doing this from controller would issue only one query.

Answer (score 3):

Ecto supports nested preloading for this purpose. You just need to change:

```
|> Repo.preload(:rsvps)
```

to:

```
|> Repo.preload(rsvps: [:user])
```

in the controller and all the RSVPs of all the Meetups will have their `user` field preloaded efficiently.

---

You should pretty much never call preload in a loop (`for` / `Enum.each` / `Enum.map` etc) as it defeats the main purpose of preloading -- [avoiding N+1 queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-select-n1).